# Can not store json obj in state when i use useEffect to get an object from an API

Tags: json, reactjs, state

Im trying to show an object's properties on a modal, but nothing seems to happen after i fetch it. I've tried without using the useEffect hook, and it does store the item but then i cant access the properties, i asked about it, and a user told me to use use Effect. But now, nothing seems to be stored...

This is my code:

```
  import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Modal = ({ handleClose, show, id }) => {
    const showHideClassName = show ? "mod displayBlock" : "mod displayNone";
    const [peliSeleccionada, setPeli] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost/APIpeliculas/api/pelicula/read_single.php/?ID=${id}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                result => {
                    alert(result); //the alerts dont even pop up
                    setPeli(result);
                    alert(peliSeleccionada);
                });
    }, []);
    
    return (
      <div className={showHideClassName}>
        <section className="mod-main">
            <h5>EDITAR: </h5>
            <label> 
                { peliSeleccionada.Nombre } 
            </label>
            <div className="btn-grupo">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Guardar cambios</button>
                <button onClick={handleClose} type="button" className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
};

export default Modal;
```

The alerts i put inside my useEffect function dont even pop up, and i also get this error on the console as soon as i enter the page:

*Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0*

Also I want to access my object's properties, which are: ID, Nombre, Categoria, and Director. Is this the correct way to do it? { peliSeleccionada.Nombre }

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` is run after the component renders, similarly to how `componentDidMount` works.
What this means, putting it very simply, is that the component will `return` and then fire the fetch.

There is an issue with your `peliSeleccionada` state, you declare it as an array but call `peliSeleccionada.Nombre` like if it was an object. This means that on first render it will print `undefined` for the `peliSeleccionada.Nombre`.

An approach to have this is to pair it with a `loading` state.

```
const Modal = () => {
  const [loaded, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [peliSeleccionada, setPeli] = useState({});

  useEffect( () => {
    fetch()
     .then(res => { 
       setPeli(res) // parse this accordingly
     }) // or chain of thens if needed
     .catch(err => {
       setLoading(false);
       console.log(err) // something failed in the fetch. You could have another state to mark that the fetching failed; close the modal, show an error, etc.
     })
  }, [])

  if(!loaded) return 'Loading...'

  return (<div>Data goes here</div>) // be careful if the fetch failed, it won't show data!

}
```

Last but not least, the error is happening in the fetch and the message states exactly that, that you are not catching it. If it is in the `fetch` call, the above code works. If it is in a parsing, it might require a `try/catch` around the `useEffect`